# When I try to fetch data from database in python nothing appear from the output Qmsg?

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, pyqt5

I work on a registration and login system in python, the registration process works 100% but when I try login in and executing this code, nothing appears? what's the problem I have tried a different query?
and I try to check the debugger but also not helpful.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPlainTextEdit, \
QApplication, QComboBox, QMainWindow, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QMessageBox

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QDialog
from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon
from win32com import *
import mysql.connector  
import mysql.connector as mc
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi`


#connect to database
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root")
# creating cursor for SQL operation
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor(buffered=True)#

#********Login Window
class Login(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Login,self).__init__()
    self.setFixedWidth(1030)
    self.setFixedHeight(590)

    loadUi("loginW.ui",self)
    self.back.setStyleSheet("background-image : url(MainBack.png)")
    self.back.resize(1060, 625)
    self.LoginButton.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)
    self.ReButton.clicked.connect(self.Register)
#******check if the user exist
def loginfunction(self):
    email=self.email.text()
    Password1=self.Password.text()
    if db_connection.is_connected() == False:
        db_connection.connect()
    db_cursor = db_connection.cursor("use User")
    query = "SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email ='%s' AND password ='%s'" % (email, Password1)
    try:
        db_cursor.execute(query)
        result = db_cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
    # ********* If the user info not correct show msgbox
        if result :
            msgf = QMessageBox()
            msgf.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msgf.setText("Incorrect email or password ")
            msgf.setInformativeText("Please try again")
            msgf.setWindowTitle("Warning!")
    #********** If user exist go to prof/std window.
        else:
            print('hi')
    except mc.Error as e:
        msgf = QMessageBox()
        msgf.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msgf.setText("Something wrong happened!")
        msgf.setInformativeText("Please try login again")
        msgf.setWindowTitle("Warning!")


#*****Go to Register Window
def Register(self):
    ReWin.show()
```

Comment: Add `msgf.exec_()` at the end of the the `if result:` and `except` blocks, or use the [static functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#static-public-members) instead of creating the message boxes from scratch.

Comment: Thank you it's work. but still, give an exception!

Comment: If you don't tell us *what* exception (and don't use the correct except tracking), we cannot help you.

Comment: I use mc. Error as e exception,  and in debugger result a raise errors.get_exception(packet)      (<class 'mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError(1046, '1046 (3D000): No database selected', '3D000'), <traceback object at 0x0000026A68B54F00>)

Comment: @Tuqa The error message seems clear enough. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: @ekhumoro I solve it, thank you.